# Geolocation precision

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I programmed this code but there is a problem, the code works but if I open it and don't open maps on my phone before opening script the location is not precise, but if I open maps(in maps I'm located with precise +/- 1 meter) than I get redirected accurately. Is there any way to put in my script that user is located precise like in maps?

```
if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError);
}
else {
    alert("Vaš preglednik ne podržava geolokaciju.");
}

function showError(error) {
    switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            alert("Molimo dopustite lociranje kako bi stranica pravilno radila.");
            break;

        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            alert("Nema informacija o vašoj lokaciji.");
            break;

        case error.TIMEOUT:
            alert("Vrijeme slanja zahtjeva isteklo.");
            break;

        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            alert("Oops. Dogodila se nepoznata greška.");
            break;
    }
}

function showPosition(pos) {
    //Neboder
    if (pos.coords.latitude <= 45.77578 && pos.coords.latitude >= 45.77502 && pos.coords.longitude <= 15.995222 && pos.coords.longitude >= 15.994286)
    {window.location = 'mob_test.html';}


    //Vrtic
    if (pos.coords.latitude <= 45.774885 && pos.coords.latitude >= 45.774754 && pos.coords.longitude <= 15.993956 && pos.coords.longitude >= 15.993886) {
    window.location = 'vrtic.html';}

    //Restoran      
    if (pos.coords.latitude <= 45.774896 && pos.coords.latitude >= 45.774748 && pos.coords.longitude <= 15.993792 && pos.coords.longitude >= 15.993671) {
        window.location = 'skola.html';
    }
    //Ostalo     
    else {
        window.location = 'bljak.html';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML5 Geolocation API has options, which one of is enableHighAccuracy. Try setting that option to true and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError, { enableHighAccuracy: true });
}